# import file.exe into Android

Tags: java, c, android-ndk

I have an exe file generated from a C library using Visual Studio. I want to call it from Android. is that possible? If i can generate a ready file.so  and add it as a jni project into android, without the need to change the C code.

Comment: It has to be compiled for the platform. But generally it is possible.

Comment: You'll have to recompile the library using the NDK so that it is binary compatible with the android platform. Then you'll have to create the native stubs to invoke it from the java code, which involves JNI code.

Comment: i cannot recompile it without using NDK? because i tried and its not working because of mixing non native and native calls. Some native functions has to call pure C functions.

Comment: You can run executable on Android. It's not even necessary to make file.so with JNI. But you should use a compatible NDK toolchain.

Comment: "Some native functions has to call pure C functions" this does not make sense - "native" and "C" refer to the same thing.  If your source is a C# or .NET type project, you have a lot more work to do in adapting it than just feeding it to a compiler (yes, there are obscure attempts to implement .NET on Android - you can research that but rewriting is likely best)

Comment: thanx @ChrisStratton, i have solved that already :)